# How to recursively transform this object?

Tags: javascript, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I want to recursively traverse an object and modify it.

For the object below, I want to recursively traverse `children` until I reach a child which has no children and only `text` property. If the text is "\n" I want to merge that text to the previous node's text.

For example below I want to merge the "\n" with "Coffee subscription" so that that node becomes "Coffee subscription\n".

```
{
  children: [
    {
      type: "p",
      align: "left",
      children: [
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://lesoursonsdecyrillignac.com/13-je-choisis-mon-abonnement",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Cyril Lignac chocolate ourson subscription "
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410725
        },
        {
          text: "(yes it's a thing!)\n"
        }
      ],
      id: 1639536410578
    },
    {
      type: "p",
      align: "left",
      children: [
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://souleilwines.com/",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Souleil wines"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410796
        },
        {
          text: " "
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://twoworldswhiskey.com/",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Two Worlds"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410684
        },
        {
          text: " "
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://cafesbelleville.com/products/abonnement-cafe?variant=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Whiskey "
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410852
        },
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://cafesbelleville.com/products/abonnement-cafe?variant=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Coffee subscription"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410745
        },
        {
          text: "\n"
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://www.whisky.fr/st-germain-coffret-marin-montagut.html?et_keyword=&et_campaign=14410606289&et_device=c&et_matchtype=&gclid=CjwKCAiAtdGNBhAmEiwAWxGcUv0XcH_0P0lg1oKlJifpBB5BiuGmUen4GkPv2ObJW5R78U1Sz3F52BoCVI4QAvD_BwEnt=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Limited Edition Liqueur Saint Germain x Marin Montagut"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410608
        },
        {
          text: " \nSubscription to the "
        },

        {
          text: " "
        }
      ],
      id: 1639536410749
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```js
{
  children: [
    {
      type: "p",
      align: "left",
      children: [
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://lesoursonsdecyrillignac.com/13-je-choisis-mon-abonnement",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Cyril Lignac chocolate ourson subscription "
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410725
        },
        {
          text: "(yes it's a thing!)\n"
        }
      ],
      id: 1639536410578
    },
    {
      type: "p",
      align: "left",
      children: [
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://souleilwines.com/",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Souleil wines"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410796
        },
        {
          text: " "
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url: "https://twoworldswhiskey.com/",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Two Worlds"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410684
        },
        {
          text: " "
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://cafesbelleville.com/products/abonnement-cafe?variant=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Whiskey "
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410852
        },
        {
          text: ""
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://cafesbelleville.com/products/abonnement-cafe?variant=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Coffee subscription\n"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410745
        },
        {
          type: "a",
          url:
            "https://www.whisky.fr/st-germain-coffret-marin-montagut.html?et_keyword=&et_campaign=14410606289&et_device=c&et_matchtype=&gclid=CjwKCAiAtdGNBhAmEiwAWxGcUv0XcH_0P0lg1oKlJifpBB5BiuGmUen4GkPv2ObJW5R78U1Sz3F52BoCVI4QAvD_BwEnt=25030347718756",
          children: [
            {
              text: "Limited Edition Liqueur Saint Germain x Marin Montagut"
            }
          ],
          id: 1639536410608
        },
        {
          text: " \nSubscription to the "
        },

        {
          text: " "
        }
      ],
      id: 1639536410749
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code I'm trying:

```js
const transform = ({ type, children = [], ...rest }) => {
  if (children) {
    if (children) {
      console.log("Children", children);
      return {
        type,
        ...rest,
        ...(children.children.length
          ? { children: children.children.map(transform) }
          : {})
      };
    } else {
      return {
        type,
        ...rest,
        ...(children.length ? { children: children.map(transform) } : {})
      };
    }
  } else {
    if (rest.text && rest.text === "\n") {
      const index = children.indexOf(rest);
      console.log(children, children[index], index, JSON.stringify(rest));
    }
  }
};

function parse_blocks() {
  transform({ children: payload });
}
```

Comment: Add the expected output

Comment: @RameshReddy Ok I have added it

Comment: `if (children) { if (children) {` doesn't make sense, the two conditions will always evaluate the same. And `children` will never be falsy anyway since you default it to an empty array. Also none of your `children` objects has a `.children` property, so `children.children.length` will cause an exception. Did you mean to test for `children.length == 1 && children[0].children`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes I want to keep looping until there are no children left, For ex: it has only text: "some text etc"